# How to identify model of Shimano levers/brifters?

Tags: replacement, shimano-di2, brifters

Sticky Shimano Brake Hoods

How do I find out what brake hoods I have on Shimano levers? Mine have become tacky and sticky and adhere to my gloves!

I have Di2 Ultegra and not sure if the levers are ST-R8050 -see pic attached. Someone said pull back the rubber hoods and there should be a code-mine have  PA-GF underneath a recycling sign!

Any thoughts?

Comment: NB the photo has not been attached successfully, if you can try again that will be most helpful

Comment: PA-GF is Polyamid Glass-Fibre reinforced plastic, its the recycling mark for end-of-life.  Not helpful here sorry.  Or maybe its `Pennsylvania Gluten-Free`...

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. I managed to get a pair from Bikester- all UK places sold out!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rim brake cable (not hydraulic) Di2 Ultegra 8000 series, your shifters are indeed ST-R8050.  A picture is available at the below link.

[Shimano Link to Right ST-R8050 lever](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/ultegra-r8050-di2/ST-R8050-R.html)

The hydraulic brake Di2 version is the ST-R8070.  It is very slightly different from the ST-R8050 in the picture at this link.

[Shimano Link to Right ST-R8070 lever](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/ultegra-r8050-di2/ST-R8070-R.html)

However, if it is not Ultegra 8000 series (or even if it is), you could likely match what you have with the information for replacement "Bracket Covers," which is what Shimano calls the rubber hoods on your shifters.  From the following link you can select from a list of covers, and from each individual cover, you can link to the original product for a picture (to match with your existing shifters).

[Shimano Bracket Covers](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/service-upgradeparts/road/category/bracket-cover.html)